# How can I keep git cvsimport from skipping patchsets?

Tags: git, cvs

I'm trying to import a cvs module into an existing git repo. I can get it to work properly if I import into a fresh repo, but when I try to import into the existing repo it seems determined to skip all the patchsets that are dated before the last commit to the branch that I've specified with -o. This is what I'm currently trying:

```
git cvsimport -v -p -x -o cvs -d <cvsroot> -k -u <module>
```

The end of the output consists of lines like this:

```
skip patchset 26: 1258578534 before 1259081502
```

If I drop the "-o cvs", it fails with:

```
Branch 'origin' does not exist. 
Either use the correct '-o branch' option, 
or import to a new repository.
```

So, how can I get git cvsimport to import *everything*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve -- do you want the new commits from CVS to sit after what's in git in the branch, or to modify existing commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import into a new repository, duplicate the new branch into your current repository then re-write the branch to sit after what you've already got, if that's what you're after.

Alternatively, if you're trying to replicate a multi-module CVS checkout by converting a module at a time, you may want to try to convert it all at once...

It may work to convert each module to git, pull each branch into a single repository then create a commit with each branch head as a parent, putting each module in the correct place in the tree.  This doesn't do a good job of preserving concurrency in the individual modules' history.

Comment: The CVS repository contains a very large number of modules, but I'm actually only trying to convert a few. So doing it all at once doesn't seem like a great idea in this case.

I'm currently experimenting with your third suggestion and it seems like it's doing what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is simple:

- Create a new git repository yourself (don't let cvsimport do this)
- Commit an initial commit
- Set the date of that initial commit way back in the past

Hence:

```
$ mkdir my_repo
$ cd my_repo
$ git init
$ touch test
$ git add test
$ git commit -m "Initial commit" --date="1990-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Now run git cvsimport with the -C flag pointing to your git repository folder. git cvsimport will skip patches with timestamps before the head of your branch (see -o flag).

Comment: I was having a similar problem (huge CVS repo; only want a few modules) and cvsimport was failing. I tried the above commit --date trick, but cvsimport still failed w/ "Branch 'origin' does not exist." git log shows only one item, commit bb7778de12614b1c844a4d124884c3b745f80519
Author: ...
Date:   Tue Jan 1 00:00:00 1980 -0500